# Why is this object undefined even though based on it, its data is displayed on the .html component

Tags: angular, typescript

I don't understand why the object "student" is undefined in the context below when I try to, based on it, access a variable of that object (a list of other objects).
What I mean is this:

In the code below there are "student" and "courses" objects.
The "student" object has the attribute "courses" which is of "Courses[]" type.
I want to, based on that "student" object's "courses" attribute, populate the "courses" object inside of the class. I hope I'm clear on what I mean.

**My question**: Why is the "student" object reported as "undefined", even though based on it, I'm populating the contents of the .html component of that page?

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Student } from '../student';
import { Course } from '../course';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

import { StudentsService }  from '../students.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-student-detail',
  templateUrl: './student-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./student-detail.component.css']
})
export class StudentDetailComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() student: Student;
  courses: Course[];

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private studentsService: StudentsService,
    private location: Location
  ) {}

  private jmbagId: string;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getStudent();
  }

  getStudent(): void {
    this.jmbagId = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('jmbag');
    this.studentsService.getStudent(this.jmbagId)
      .subscribe(student => this.student = student);
    console.log(this.student);
  }

}
```

**Working HTML**

```html
<li *ngFor="let course of student.courses">
```

**What I'm wondering why isn't it working about HTML**

```html
<li *ngFor="let course of courses">
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular)

Comment: If you are asking why ```this.student``` console undefined then put your ```console.log(this.student)```  inside subscribe and it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.studentsService.getStudent(this.jmbagId)
  .subscribe(student => this.student = student);
console.log(this.student);
```

It is async so this.student will be undefined at first